# How to get the current date running on my MongoDB instance using spring data or pure java

Tags: java, mongodb

Is that anyway to get the current date from my MongoDB database server, using spring data or pure java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the $eval command to get the current date by calling javascript like new Date(), new ISODate(), ISODate. More here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Date/

```
Document doc = db.runCommand(new Document("$eval", "new Date()"));
Date current = (Date) doc.get("retval");
```