# How to push $currentdate into field array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

Suppose that I have a **nodes** documents like this:

```
{
  _id: 0,
  lastPing: ISODate("2016-12-27T00:37:31.828Z"),
  last10Pings: [ISODate("2016-12-27T00:35:31.828Z"), ISODate("2016-12-27T00:37:31.828Z"), ...]
}
```

lastPing will store the latest update from client while last10Pings will store last 10 update from client.

Updating lastPing is quite easy with this query from a **client**:

```
db.nodes.update({_id: 0}, {$currentDate: {lastPing: true}});
```

Updating last10Pings is also not a problem when try to update from a **server**:

```
db.nodes.update({_id: 0}, {$push: {last10Pings: {$each: [new Date()], $slice: 10}}});
```

Now I ran into a difficulty problem. I want to push server time (something like $currentDate) into last10Pings with **query made from client**. I can not use `new Date()` from client since it will use local time instead of server time.

Comment: Not sure what problem you are running into. You can create UTC date in your language and pass it to the date field.

Comment: @SagarReddy In case that my application running on another PC that has time different from my server. The time added from client side is not reliable.

Comment: Just set to UTC time. It's global time. That's how records are saved in mongo db server too.

Comment: I have Raspberry Pi running on Raspbian. I made a ssh tunnel to my mongod on the server. The Raspberry Pi itself has no RTC and sometime it fails to get time from internet. I able to make a ping back to my server by the first query which use $currentDate. As my requirement, I want to keep record of last 10 ping so I want to make a query that push $currentDate into an array rather than in a single field.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get the $currrentDate for the array , but you can get the current time from server. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40935782/2683814. Hope it helps.